# Why Single-Page Web Application

Tags: asp.net, html, single-page-application

While Single-Page application approach is rising as a web development choice, I still don't understand, practically, how would losing the ability to go back/forward in the browser be an O.K sacrifice? Imagine Facebook without direct page navigation! Is there an essential/direct purpose for SPA I can't get my hands on?

Comment: You don't lose the ability to go back and forward.  Time to change SPA frameworks if that is the case!  Advantages include avoiding full postback cycles and perceived snappier performance by the user.

Comment: @JasonCoder you might be right. But how about direct page navigation? is that covered in newer frameworks too?

Comment: @yazanpro - you seem to have a lot of (wrong) pre-conceived notions about SPA's.  There's nothing that prevents direct page navigation with a SPA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wont have to give up back button functionality to develop a single page application. HTML5 has a history api (and there's polyfills for older browsers) which allows your to keep back button functioning properly.

The main reason (in my opinion) to go for a single page approach is the more app-like feel it gives you. For example gmail feels more like an app than a web page, and given its purpose, I think that's way it should be too. Another example might be the [pixlr online image editor](http://pixlr.com/editor/).

Single page approach indeed doesn't suit every purpose, but when you want a web**app** to feel just that, instead of a web**site**, then single page might be the way to go.

You mentioned direct navigation in comments, and that's totally doable if it's something that makes sense in your context. Angularjs can do that, and I'm sure pretty much every modern single page framework has a way of implementing this.

Comment: Thanks, but again (I asked JasonCoder the same question), how about direct page navigation? we are giving this up in SPA aren't we?